# What materials do you need to repair the Champion Weapons?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

After constructing the Boulder Breaker, the goron smith informed me that he would be able to repair it if it breaks, given the materials. What materials do you need to repair the Boulder Breaker?

I assume the Great Eagle Bow, the Scimitar of the Seven, and the Lightscale Trident can also be repaired with materials. What materials do I need to repair those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no *normal* way of repairing the Champion Weapons in Tears of the Kingdom, unlike Breath of the Wild.

However, people have discovered a work-around that seems like an inconvenient albeit possible solution if you feel the need to repair a Champion Weapon before it is destroyed.

Once you unlock the **Break-a-Part Shop** in **Tarrey Town**, you can unfuse items from your weapons without losing either component for a small Rupee fee.

Additionally, you can throw weapons to octorocks to repair them. Normally this doesn't work for Champion weapons, but if you attach a champion weapon *to* another weapon, it will get repaired by the octorock by extension.

Once it's repaired, you can get it defused by Pelison, and re-fuse whatever you wanted to the Champion weapon, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The boulder breaker requires 3 diamonds to forge in the first place...

Comment: Also, the Scimitar of the Seven is made at the same time as the Daybreaker, in a set called the Arms of the Seven.

Comment: This looks like the BotW forge costs, not the TotK ones.

Comment: @User23415 You're completely right, I got them mixed up. I'm going to try and edit with correct information. I'd delete it but it's already accepted so I can't...